# how to compare expected value to be in the list

Tags: protractor

how to compare expected value to be in the list

`IncPanel.IncList.count().then(function(count){ 
                            for(var i=0; i< count; i++){ CommonFun.getIncCurrentState(i).then(function(State){
                       switch(State){
                                    case "created":
                                        expect(State).toContain('created');
                                        break;
                                    case "open":
                                        expect(State).toContain('open');
                                        break;
                                    case "escalated":
                                        expect(State).toContain('escalated');
                                        break;
                                    case "closed":
                                        expect(State).toContain('closed');
                                        break;
                                };
                            });
                        };
                    });`
Is there any way in Protractor so that I can compare expected value to be anything in the List, I mean how can I change above switch statement to something like `expect(State).toBeIn(['created','open','escalated','closed']);`

Comment: Is there any Inbuilt function in protractor to compare expected value from the list or I have to write my custom function?

Comment: Using : expect(State).toMatch(/created|open|escalated|closed/); instead of Switch statement.